# Resize Win-Universal App whilst running another App

Tags: vb.net, win-universal-app

I am designing a front end for home automation. 
I have 6 buttons on the front screen, each launching another application.

When a button is clicked I want my app to be say a 100px bar across the top of the screen (and reduce the available screen size reported to the launched app) and be always on top. The 100px bar will simply display a home and or back button so the  main application can take focus again.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The ApplicationView class may be the right starting point for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.aspx

Comment: But: It is not going to work in Tablet Mode.